# DataTable Aggregate Function with Dynamic LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I've an old project with following function that return a DataTable with aggregate function in Linq.

Now my goal is to use aggregate function with dynamic linq getting values from json file.
I've seen different threads about using dynamic linq but there's enough confusion on them.
I'm codig with vb.net or c#.

Json file gives information about column name, column type, aggregation type etc.

I don't necessarily have to use LINQ and we could also opt for another solution.

```vb
Private Function GetTotalByIST_Dynamic(dt As DataTable) As DataTable

    Dim table2 = New DataTable()
  
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        table2.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType)
    Next

    Dim query = From dr In dt.AsEnumerable()
              Group dr By FieldGroup = dr.Field(Of String)("MyField") Into drg = Group
              Select New With {
                    .MyField= FieldGroup ,
                    .FIELD_TOTAL_UDP = drg.Sum(Function(dr) LongOrNull(dr.Field(Of String)("FIELD_TOTAL_UDP "))),
                    .FIELD2_TOTAL_UDP = drg.Sum(Function(dr) LongOrNull(dr.Field(Of String)("FIELD2_TOTAL_UDP ")))
                   }

   For Each grp In query
        Dim newRow = table2.Rows.Add()
        newRow.SetField("MyField", grp.MyField)
        newRow.SetField("FIELD_TOTAL_UDP", grp.FIELD_TOTAL_UDP)
        newRow.SetField("FIELD2_TOTAL_UDP", grp.FIELD2_TOTAL_UDP)
    Next

    Return table2
```

**UPDATE**

I've find this solution with Dynamic Linq (System.Linq.Dynamic) but there is a little piece to understand and correct.

```
 dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable.GroupBy(Function(r) r("MyField").ToString) _
 Select(Function(g) dt.Clone.LoadDataRow({g.Key}.Concat(dt.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn) _
.Skip(1).Select(Function(c) g.Sum(Function(r) If(Int32.TryParse(r(c).ToString, New Int32), Int32.Parse(r(c).ToString), 0)).ToString)).ToArray, False)) _ 
.CopyToDataTable()
```

This piece produces a new table with SUM in each column of the data table "dt" but if column used in GroupBy is not the first column in dt causes a strange result.

If my datatable "dt" has 5 columns

```
UO_DEP - UO_CITY - UO_A - UO_B - UO_C
A          ROME      5      5      5
B          ROME      10     10     10
```

Choosing UO_CITY as column in GROUP BY produces as result

```
UO_DEP - UO_CITY - UO_A - UO_B - UO_C
ROME       0        15     15      15
```

In JSON file i can locate columns for groupby and columns for sum/count/average etc.

Refering to example i don't need "UO_DEP" column in function aggregation.

How can i use only these columns in the above mentioned instruction?

Comment: _I've seen different threads about using dynamic linq but there's enough confusion on them. I'm codig with vb.net or c#_: You seem to be confused as well - you don't seem to know whether you're programming in C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Well not important. C# for library or VB.net to simplify. Stay well.